# change model value in javascript

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

For example I've got model attribute `curPage` on my jsp page.
How to change its value in javascript function?

Something like this

```
function prev() {
    var curPage = '${curPage}'; //get value
    if (curPage > 1) 
        curPage--; //modify it
    '${curPage}' = curPage;
}
```

Comment: What is `'${curPage]'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is executed on the client side, while the model attributes exist on your server.

In case of your example above, the `${curPage}` will be replaced with the value of $curPage at runtime and the javascript would be sent to your client. Any modifications you make to the curPage variable will stay on the client side.

If you want to persist this change to your server, you need to make some kind of web request back to the server(ajax, form submit  etc.)

Comment: I see. I wanted to avoid it but it seems it's not possible